# Get all Laravel artisan commands for interface

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

When you use `php artisan` in the command line you get a list of all commands. Are there any opportunity to get all Laravel artisan commands programmatically? I need it for example to use it in a select field in the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all command objects:

```
\Artisan::all()
```

To get all command names:

```
array_keys(\Artisan::all())
```

Comment: Can i get all commands from specific folder?
And also can i get all commands with conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Use shell-exec command.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

```
$output = shell_exec('php artisan');
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel;
...
$commands = resolve(Kernel::class)->all();
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in your routes like this:

```
Route::get('/foo', function()
{
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('command:name', ['--option' => 'foo']);

//
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/artisan#calling-commands-outside-of-cli

Answer (score 0):

if I understand the query correctly, you can use CLI (eg bash in debian) to:

1. `&&` for individual calls - each subsequent call will be made after the previous performance, eg:

   `php artisan migrate:fresh && php artisan fixtures:up && php artisan db:seed && php artisan serv`
2. aliases entered in .bash_profile

   `alias migrate = "php artisan migrate"`

and using command `migrate` in Laravel project.

info: https://gist.github.com/JeffreyWay/5542264